# Why doesn't the shorthand escape_javascript actually work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, haml

**Here's my biopsis**

Works :

```
:plain
  console.log("#{escape_javascript(render(@job_charge).html_safe)}");
```

Does not work ( but should? ) :

```
:plain
  console.log("#{j render(@job_charge).html_safe }");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `j` is actually shorthand for `json_escape`, not `escape_javascript`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Comment: Interesting... it looks like one of the two was added recently and created a naming conflict: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3578

Comment: This looks like it is no longer applicable for Rails 4.2.1+, as `j` is now shorthand for `escape_javascript` and not for `json_escape`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j vs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-json_escape

Answer (score 1):

`j` is shorthand for `json_escape`.

`escape_javascript` also exists (at least in rails 3.x) but does something different - it escapes strings for use inside javascript string literals.

I guess the first sample is failing for a different reason.  Check your log!

Answer (score 0):

`j` is, indeed, shorthand for `escape_javascript` according to the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j

I use it all the time and it works.